# To know which time period have many records

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the table like below .
The Condition of Time Period is 0 to 6, 7 to 12, 13 to 18 
Is there any single query to get this output ?

```
sellingMaterial  sellingTime

SAMSUNG             2
SAMSUNG             4
SAMSUNG             3
NOKIA               5
NOKIA               13
NOKIA               10
APPLE               12
APPLE               7
APPLE               15

Expected output is

Time Period   sellingMaterial    
0 to 6        SAMSUNG
```

Comment: Sure, it is.  But have you tried anything by yourself? Please show your efforts first :o) otherwise you have good chance for http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I tried the below query in BigQuery.
SELECT sellingTime,sellingMaterial FROM kali.material
group by 
sellingTime between 0 and 6,
sellingTime between 7 and 12,
sellingTime between 13 and 18

But I got below error.
 (L4:15): expression BETWEEN([sellingTime], 0, 6) in GROUP BY is invalid

Comment: see my answer then. meantime, please move info about query that you tried along with error - into the question itself - you can do it using Edit link below the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT start, finish,
  STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT(sellingMaterial, ':', CAST(volume AS STRING)) 
    ORDER BY volume DESC, sellingMaterial
  ) sellingMaterial
FROM (
  SELECT start, finish, sellingMaterial, COUNT(1) volume
  FROM `project.dataset.conditions` c
  JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
  ON sellingTime BETWEEN start AND finish
  GROUP BY start, finish, sellingMaterial
)
GROUP BY start, finish
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'SAMSUNG' sellingMaterial, 2 sellingTime UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SAMSUNG', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SAMSUNG', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NOKIA', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NOKIA', 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NOKIA', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'APPLE', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'APPLE', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'APPLE', 15 
), `project.dataset.conditions` AS (
  SELECT 0 start, 6 finish UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 18 
)
SELECT start, finish,
  STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT(sellingMaterial, ':', CAST(volume AS STRING)) 
    ORDER BY volume DESC, sellingMaterial
  ) sellingMaterial
FROM (
  SELECT start, finish, sellingMaterial, COUNT(1) volume
  FROM `project.dataset.conditions` c
  JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
  ON sellingTime BETWEEN start AND finish
  GROUP BY start, finish, sellingMaterial
)
GROUP BY start, finish
-- ORDER BY start
```

with result

```
Row start   finish  sellingMaterial  
1   0       6       SAMSUNG:3,NOKIA:1    
2   7       12      APPLE:2,NOKIA:1  
3   13      18      APPLE:1,NOKIA:1
```

> I want which time have most records [sellingMaterial]

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'SAMSUNG' sellingMaterial, 2 sellingTime UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SAMSUNG', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SAMSUNG', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NOKIA', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NOKIA', 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NOKIA', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'APPLE', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'APPLE', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'APPLE', 15 
), `project.dataset.conditions` AS (
  SELECT 0 start, 6 finish UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 18 
)
SELECT start, finish, sellingMaterial
FROM `project.dataset.conditions` c
JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
ON sellingTime BETWEEN start AND finish
GROUP BY start, finish, sellingMaterial
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

with result

```
Row start   finish  sellingMaterial  
1   0       6       SAMSUNG
```

Comment: I want which time have many records. Above query show all record.

Comment: by many  - you mean most? this was not clear from your question - clarify please

Comment: Yes , I mean most